# How to Handle scrolling in view and subview(Graph)

Tags: ios, uiview, graph, uiscrollview, core-plot

I have a UIScrollview with UIView and a subview i,e graph(CPTGraphHostingView) of scatter plot within uiview.
I am facing an problem in scrolling the graph (horizontally and vertically) because main scroll is enabled.
Please refer a below image for clear description.
Please let me know how to solve this issue so that it should scroll both in main view and graph.[image]

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIScrollView` normally captures all of the touch events and doesn't pass them to its subviews. Subclass it and override the `-touchesXXX:withEvent:` methods. Pass the set of events to the graph if they're within the graph, otherwise pass it to `super` to let the scroll view handle it.